# Is there a way to get the object which called my static method as an instance method?

Tags: java, static

We all know that in Java you can call a static method as an instance method like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
FooBar fooBar = foo.bar(); // bar is a static method on class Foo
```

What I want to know is:

- Is there any way to determine inside `bar` whether `bar` was called statically (`Foo.bar()`) or called via a class instance as above?
- If so, is there any way for `bar` to get a reference to the object which called it (in this case `foo`)?

Reason:

I am developing a kind of semantic syntax. I want my consumers to be able to put things like:

```
With.attribute("blah").and().attribute("blahblah"); // both "attribute" and "and" methods return an object of type "With"
```

Here you can see that `attribute` is being called both as a static and an instance method. However, you can't define a static and an instance method with the same name in Java, for the same reason as above - the static method could be called as an instance method and so to create an instance method with the same name would create ambiguity. Therefore I want to create a single method `attribute` which can be called both statically and non-statically, and inside the method body I want to try to determine if it was invoked statically or non-statically. The above questions will help me to assess the feasibility of doing this.

Comment: It's still being called statically; there's no difference internally. So no: it's not being called as an instance method.

Comment: If you called it statically there's no way to get the Object. You can achieve that type of method though if you use the object and return it as a value so you can do .and() and futher more do .attribute

Comment: You could provide a static `with()` method that returns a new instance.

Comment: there is no such thing as *static method being called as an instance method*, a `static` method can only be referred to `statically` the fact that Java allows the `dot` syntax to reference static methods of that class from instances is the cause of this confusion and was a bad design choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way for the method to know whether it was called on a class or on an instance (at the JVM level there is no difference), and there is no way to get the instance that the method was called on.

The term for this kind of "semantic syntax" is [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (DSL).

Possible solution: name the static method `withAttribute`, then you could make it look like this:

```
withAttribute("blah").and().attribute("blahblah");
```

Comment: what they are doing is called `fluent api` not a `DSL` the two are completely different.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This is a good example of an [internal DSL](http://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html). And a fluent API can be regarded as a small DSL.

Comment: Good possible solution, although the class is called `With` which rather messes up the semantics. I could call the class `W` though and put `W.ithAttribute("blah").and().attribute("blahblah");` - gotta love Java....

Comment: @Kidburla You could use a static import: `import static com.mypackage.With.withAttribute;` then you can immediately use `withAttribute` without the need to put `With.` in front of it.

Answer (score -1):

Java isn't made to do this, because it is not a very good thing to do.

If you want to be able to do something like this, why not do something like

```
new foo().withAttribute("blah").withAttribute("blahblah");
```

It really isn't a very good idea to do this at all.
Plus, why are you making your consumers use java code to give instructions? why not do something like

```
make a foo //Check for and chop off "make a" to get the object to create
add attribute blah //Check for and chop off "add attribute" to get the attribute to add
add attribute blahblah //Or, if you can add other things too, check for and chop off "add", then check for and chop off "attribute"
```

It seems like that would be much simpler.

Comment: Why are you saying this is not a good idea? Domain-specific languages are quite popular, and this is a technique that is used in several well-known frameworks. For example the JPA criteria API. Do you have any good reason to say this is not good, other than that you're unfamiliar with it, or personal preference?

Comment: I mean that instead of saying new foo().bar(), you should do foo.bar().
Calling static methods from an instance isn't very good to do.

Comment: I agree that calling static methods on an instance is in general not a good thing to do.